# Why was my edit rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

The original poster of this question later posted an answer, but as a comment:

[Bootstrap inline text box and search button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796235/bootstrap-inline-text-box-and-search-button/22796612#comment34762677_22796612)

To tidy the answer up I copied the code from the comment into the parent answer and ensured it was formatted correctly. I also added a link to example working:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6873193

It was rejected because

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer.

That doesn't make any sense to me - I wasn't trying to address the author at all.

Comment: Would have to agree that the reason doesn't make sense.

Comment: The rejection reason isn't great, but I would not recommend adding code to an answer's post if the answerer did not write the code himself.

Comment: @KevinB how does it not make sense?  Adding a whole bunch of new content should be added as a new answer, not an edit, which is what the rejection reason is saying.  It's exactly right.

Comment: @Servy the other option would be for the op (where the code came from) to self answer (or worse - add it to the question as an "edit"). Gareth is adding the op's fix to the op's code to the answer to show what change should be made to fix the problem.

Comment: I take that rejection reason as having two parts. The reason for the rejection, and the action that should have happened instead. You're ignoring the first part.

Comment: @MichaelT That should still be in another answer.  Ideally it would be from the OP, if not then by someone saying that it was the OP's solution.

Comment: I do agree the edit should have been rejected, but I also agree with Gareth in that the reason chosen doesn't really describe what is wrong with the edit. Invalid edit wouldn't be much better, but at least it wouldn't say the edit was trying to address the author when it clearly wasn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content.  They're not there for you to add your own entirely new and original content.

The information that you're providing is significant enough that it should really be in a separate answer; this is exactly what the rejection reason is saying.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, and I accept it doesn't make sense to add someone else's code to the answer. I've created a new answer instead, and linked to the comment where the OP posted their answer

Comment: Garett, you should make the answer a complete one - not just a copy of the comment.

Comment: @GarethOakley I don't see the link as anything the author posted.  You should make it clear that it's not the author's link.  Additionally, if you're going to post it, it needs context.  Don't just stick a link in there; explain what it is, what is on the other side of the link, and why a reader might want to follow it.